# Why is my request to the Goodreads API returning undefined?

Tags: node.js, http, request, npm

Below is a short example of how I'm using the request module in NPM.  It returns undefined, and I'm fairly certain I'm using xml2js correctly.  Am I misusing the 'form' option in the request module to pass values to the Goodreads API?  Thanks!

```
var req = require('request');

var resp = req.get('https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn_to_id', {form:{
    'key' : '*****************',
    'isbn' : '9780060513030'
}});

var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

parseString(resp, function (err, result) {
    console.dir(result);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an asynchronous API based on callbacks, not promises or regular return values.

```
var req = require('request');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

req.get('https://www.goodreads.com/book/isbn_to_id', {form:{
    'key' : '*****************',
    'isbn' : '9780060513030'
}}, function (error, response, body) {
  //error handling goes here!
  parseString(body, function (err, result) {
    //error handling goes here, too!
    console.dir(result);
  });
});
```